# NLog - Having Performance issues and logs are always writing to one file rather than multiple file

Tags: nlog

**I have my nlog confiiguration as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlog throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
        <target name="file" type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
            <target type="BufferingWrapper" name="file" bufferSize="120">
                <target type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/MyApplicationLog.log" layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring} ${message} ${newline}" archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/MyApplicationLogArchive/MyApplicationLog_{##}.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="30" />
            </target>
        </target>
        <target name="MyApplicationHandlerLog" type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
            <target type="BufferingWrapper" name="file" bufferSize="120">
                <target type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/MyApplicationHandlerLog.log" layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring} ${message} ${newline}" archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/MyApplicationHandlerLogArchive/MyApplicationHandlerLog_{##}.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="30" />
            </target>
        </target>
        <target name="MyApplicationHandlerMetrics" type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
            <target type="BufferingWrapper" name="file" bufferSize="120">
                <target type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/MyApplicationHandlerMetrics.log" layout="${longdate} ${exception:format=tostring} ${message} ${newline}" archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/MyApplicationHandlerMetricsArchive/MyApplicationHandlerMetrics_{##}.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="30" />
            </target>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="MyApplicationHandlerLog" minlevel="Info" writeTo="MyApplicationHandlerLog" />
        <logger name="MyApplicationHandlerMetrics" minlevel="Info" writeTo="MyApplicationHandlerMetrics" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am facing multiple issues listed below - need your help to sort them.

1. Perfomance issues - **I have enabled KeepFileOpen in the targets which improved the performance drastically.But have read somewhere that we need to set openFileCacheTimeout as well to make the performance optimistic. Is this true? or will it screw the performance if both are set?**
2. Not Writing the logs to multiple files as in the rules - **But is not working as expected.All logs getting written to MyApplicationHandlerMetrics**
3. Archiving works as expected - "No issues I am facing at the moment"
4. **Greatly appreciated if any suggestion can be given to improve the performance as my system deals with 140 messages/second**

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: It's preferred to ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Performance issues. Yes performance will be better using KeepFileOpen=true. openFileCacheTimeout will help NLog versions older than 4.4.2 to recover from file-problems. Use a timeout of 10 mins and no performance hit will be seen.
2. Pretty sure that it is a problem at your end, and not an issue in NLog. Have you checked the [Internal Log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) ? Maybe start with a simple configuration that works, and extend from there?
3. Great
4. Well NLog ver. 4.4.2 can handle over 200.000 messsages/second, when using a SSD-disk.

Comment: Just noticed that after upgrading from Nlog 4.1.2 to 4.6.3 dropped the performance x3 times. Still investigating why, but that was caused merely by changing the NLog NuGet package version.

Comment: @JurijsKastanovs Please create bug-issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose (And fill out the template with as much information as you can find). Random guess is that your nlog-config triggers callsite-capture, but only NLog 4.6.3 recognizes this.

Comment: It seems that only db logging dropped in performance, and only for logging the request-response in REST via MVC filters. I'll create a ticket, but meanwhile, what's this callsite-capture you're talking about? Any link to read about it? Couldn't find anything in google.

Comment: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer performs callsite-capture. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Log4JXmlEventLayout performs callsite-capture. NLog-config-items implementing `IUsesStackTrace` performs callsite-capture. But your problem sounds different when only db-target. Tried looking at the code changes between versions, and it looks harmless. Would it be possible if you could check performance with NLog ver. 4.5.11 ?